# GridView and ListView still call getView when hidden in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

I have a ViewFlipper with multiple ListViews inside. When I scroll through one ListView, `BaseAdapter.getView` is called multiple times on all the ListViews. The `ListViews` visibility is GONE. I also tried setting `setEnabled(false)` and `setClickable(false)` on the hidden `ListViews`, yet `BaseAdapter.getView` is still getting called. 
This slows down my app.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent the `ListView` from refreshing it's views?

Comment: The layout is partially generated programmatically and the code is too big to paste here. But I believe the question is clear enough.

Comment: Why don't you use a ViewPager?